# Is it possible to break out of a loop or continue to the next iteration from an external method?

Tags: c#, loops, break, continue

I have a validation method which I call in a loop.
I want to call "continue" if the validation fails.
Is there a way to call "continue" from the validation method ?
I just don't want to call "continue" in so many places in the loop...

Comment: But you can return some value in your method and check this in your loop and do the `Continue`

Comment: There might be a cleaner way to solve the given problem .. however, with almost no context it is hard to provide useful input. (The only way a called method can directly affect the "flow" of the caller is to throw an exception, but this is likely hardly appropriate.)

Comment: @MehdiKhademloo : Very much possible :) Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

No, flow control statements only affect the blocks within which they are defined. The only built-in way to alter control flow from further up the stack like that is an exception, which is definitely the wrong mechanism for what you are doing.

If you are bothered by all the `continue`s, I suggest you consider moving towards a more declarative way of thinking. Define the body of your validation loop like so:

```
bool IsValid(Foo foo) {
    if (Condition1(foo)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (Condition2(foo)) {
        return false;
    }

    // ... and so on
}
```

and then validate like this:

```
if (!foos.All(IsValid)) {
    // One of your foos is invalid
}
```

the LINQ extension methods All and Any will break execution as soon as they can, meaning that All will stop when it finds the first one that doesn't satisfy the condition and Any will stop when it finds the first one that does.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of `continue`s in your cycle and it becomes bothering. You cannot continue from the external method, as it is out of scope. There are several solutions actually though:

1. You can return a boolean value from your validation methods and then use it as such:

   `if (!IsValid()) {
       continue;
   }`

It is not helpful though, because you will still have `continue`s.

2. You can put your validations at the start of the cycle and you can use a flag to determine whether the iteration should step out, initialized by false:

   `while (myCondition) {
       stepOut = false;
       //validation region, you set stepOut to false if a validation fails
       if (!stepOut) {
           //operations
       }
   }`
3. You can wrap all the validation call into a method, let's call it `myValidation` and then:

   `while (myCondition) {
       if (myValidation()) {
           //operations
       }
   }`

or

`while (myCondition) {
    if (!IsValid()) {
        //continue
    }
}`

4. You can throw an `Exception`, but DON'T do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just return false in your validation method wherever it should return, then check if the validation method returns false, break out of loop in caller function.

Comment: I know  how to use all other solutions, I just wanted to knopw if there is any other way to do this from the external method...

Answer (score 0):

Why Not ?

Golden Rule in Programming : "There is always a way".

C++ lets you inline Assembly Language syntax. Similar to it, C# supports it too. Let me consider your example.

```
    void method1(){
      foreach(var x in y)
      {
          Validate(x);
          ...
          //Your other logic
          ...

        EndOfLoop:
          ;
      }
    }
    ..
    ..
    void Validate(T x)
    {
    #if IL
      br EndOfLoop
    #endif
    }
//End Of Code
```

This will "jump" to the "EndOfLoop" Label from anywhere within your Code. This  could be a bad practice depending on your code though..

Comment: "Is it possible to break out of a loop or continue to the next iteration" -> The answer I posted here solves this. Very much possible...  "This could be a bad practice" -> perceptions :)